# Array of Array of string works incorrectly

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I need a dynamic array of arrays of `String`.  I'm using `ArrayList`s for as my collection type.  Whatever method I try, I always have the same problem: my last call to `add()` causes the all the previous adds to fail.  I tried several methods, but still have the same problem.

Here is my test code:

```
package tests;

import org.apache.cocoon.xml.XMLUtils;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        List<String> array1 = new ArrayList();
        String e2[] = new String[2];

        // Array 1
        array1.clear();

        array1.add("A");
        array1.add("B");
        array1.add("C");
        array1.add("D");

        int nbEnregArray1 = array1.size();
        System.out.println("Nb Enreg Array1 : " +array1.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < nbEnregArray1; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enreg " + i + " : " + array1.get(i));
        }

        // ================================
        // Array 2
        // ================================
        ArrayList<String[]> array2 = new ArrayList<>();

        array2.clear();

        e2[0] = "W";
        e2[1] = "X";
        array2.add(0, e2);
        System.out.println("Array2 : Enregistrement rang 0 " + " : " + array2.get(0)[0] + " / " + array2.get(0)[1]);

        e2[0] = "C";
        e2[1] = "V";
        array2.add(1, e2);
        System.out.println("Array2 : Enregistrement rang 0 " + " : " + array2.get(0)[0] + " / " + array2.get(0)[1]);
        System.out.println("Array2 : Enregistrement rang 1 " + " : " + array2.get(1)[0] + " / " + array2.get(1)[1]);

        e2[0] = "B";
        e2[1] = "N";
        array2.add(2, e2);
        System.out.println("Array2 : Enregistrement rang 0 " + " : " + array2.get(0)[0] + " / " + array2.get(0)[1]);
        System.out.println("Array2 : Enregistrement rang 1 " + " : " + array2.get(1)[0] + " / " + array2.get(1)[1]);
        System.out.println("Array2 : Enregistrement rang 2 " + " : " + array2.get(2)[0] + " / " + array2.get(2)[1]);

        int nbEnregArray2 = array2.size();
        System.out.println("Nb Enreg Array2 : " + nbEnregArray2);

        for (int i = 0; i < nbEnregArray2; i++) {
            System.out.println("Array2 : rang " + i + " : " + array2.get(i)[0] + " / " + array2.get(i)[1]);
        }

        // ================================
        // Array3
        // ================================

        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array3 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> a3 = new ArrayList();

        array3.clear();
        String a31, a32, a33;

        a3.clear();
        a31 = "A";
        a32 = "Z";
        a3.add(a31);
        a3.add(a32);
        array3.add(a3);

        a3.clear();
        a31 = "E";
        a32 = "R";
        a3.add(a31);
        a3.add(a32);
        array3.add(a3);

        a3.clear();
        a31 = "T";
        a32 = "Y";
        a3.add(a31);
        a3.add(a32);
        array3.add(a3);

        for (int i = 0; i < array3.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Array3 : rang " + i + " : " + array3.get(i).get(0) + " / " + array3.get(i).get(1));
        }

        // ================================
        // List
        // ================================
        List<List<String>> l = new LinkedList<>();
        List<String> el = new LinkedList<>();

        l.clear();
        String l1, l2, l3;

        el.clear();
        l1 = "A";
        l2 = "Z";
        l3 = "E";
        el.add(l1);
        el.add(l2);
        el.add(l3);
        l.add(el);

        el.clear();
        l1 = "R";
        l2 = "T";
        l3 = "Y";
        el.add(l1);
        el.add(l2);
        el.add(l3);
        l.add(el);

        el.clear();
        l1 = "U";
        l2 = "I";
        l3 = "O";
        el.add(l1);
        el.add(l2);
        el.add(l3);
        l.add(el);

        for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("l : rang " + i + " : " + l.get(i).get(0) + " / " + l.get(i).get(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are adding the same List three times, so your outer List ends up with just three references to the same thing.

You'll need to make a brand new List for each insertion.

Comment: Thank you for your message. I still don't understand, because each time, I clear a list (like a3), I construct it (again a3), and then I add it to the main ArrayList (like Array3). That should work !?
Alain

Comment: But you are still operating **on the same list**! You are not making a new list object. When you add it to a list, you are simply adding a reference, and thus you are in effect adding the same list three times. Put a `a3 = new ArrayList<>()` before each `clear` and it should work...

Answer (score 0):

First of all when you are declaring a list like :

```
List<String> array1 = new ArrayList();
```

why are you using clear() even you have not added any element in it.

When you are adding a list to some other list, their values will be gone when you will use clear() as you are clearing the list which will be referred. So there values are getting overwritten

For ex -:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array3 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> a3 = new ArrayList();

array3.clear();  //no need of this as it has no elements
a3.clear();  //no need of this as it has no elements
            String a31, a32, a33;


        a31 = "A";
        a32 = "Z";
        a3.add(a31);
        a3.add(a32);
        array3.add(a3);

        a3.clear();
        a31 = "E";
        a32 = "R";
        a3.add(a31);
        a3.add(a32);
        array3.add(a3);

        a3.clear();
        a31 = "T";
        a32 = "Y";
        a3.add(a31);
        a3.add(a32);
        array3.add(a3);
```

You are clearing the old values and putting the new values so object which will be referred with new values only.

If you want to have all values to be in the last list, then you need to change clear()
as :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array3 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> a3 = new ArrayList();

        String a31, a32, a33;

        a31 = "A";
        a32 = "Z";
        a3.add(a31);
        a3.add(a32);
        array3.add(a3);

        a3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        a31 = "E";
        a32 = "R";
        a3.add(a31);
        a3.add(a32);
        array3.add(a3);

        a3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        a31 = "T";
        a32 = "Y";
        a3.add(a31);
        a3.add(a32);
        array3.add(a3);
```

You will get needed final list !!
Hope it helps and solves your query.